# MySQL INSERT: Column 'description' cannot be null but there is no column with name 'description'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute an INSERT statement on a MySQL table.
Table structure is below

```
CREATE TABLE `charges` (
  `sgl_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `opportunity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `quantity` float(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `rate` float(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `subtotal` float(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `tax` float(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `total` float(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `override_rate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `charge_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_date` date NOT NULL,
  `status_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_comment` text NOT NULL,
  `mf_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `auto_charge` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reversal_charge_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `revenue_reported` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `package_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sgl_id`),
  KEY `sgl_id_idx` (`sgl_id`),
  KEY `customer_id_idx` (`account_id`),
  KEY `opportunity_id_idx` (`opportunity_id`),
  KEY `invoice_id_idx` (`invoice_id`),
  KEY `product_id_idx` (`product_id`),
  KEY `status_id_idx` (`status_id`),
  KEY `quantity_idx` (`quantity`),
  KEY `rate_idx` (`rate`),
  KEY `tax_idx` (`tax`),
  KEY `total_idx` (`total`),
  KEY `sub_status_id_idx` (`sub_status_id`),
  KEY `mf_id_idx` (`mf_id`),
  KEY `override_rate_idx` (`override_rate`),
  KEY `created_by_idx` (`created_by`),
  KEY `charge_datetime` (`charge_datetime`),
  KEY `created_on` (`created_on`,`modified_on`,`status_date`),
  KEY `subtotal_idx` (`subtotal`),
  KEY `company_id_idx` (`company_id`),
  KEY `payment_id_idx` (`payment_id`),
  KEY `auto_charge_idx` (`auto_charge`),
  KEY `store_id_idx` (`store_id`),
  KEY `booking_id_idx` (`booking_id`),
  KEY `reversal_charge_id_idx` (`reversal_charge_id`),
  KEY `revenue_reported_idx` (`revenue_reported`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

INSERT Statement is

```
INSERT INTO charges (created_on, created_by, status_id, status_date, status_user_id, sub_status_id, account_id, product_id, comment, quantity, rate, subtotal, tax, total, override_rate, charge_datetime, modified_on, company_id, package_product_id) VALUES ('2017-09-21 09:06:27', '510', '7', '2017-09-21', '510', '59', '817350', '2331', 'Adjustment Charge', '-1', '5.00', '-5', '0', '-5', '1', '2017-09-21 09:06:27', '2017-09-21 09:06:28', '51', '0')
```

The error I'm getting is

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'description' cannot be null
```

There is no column named 'description' in the table but still, MySQL is throwing an error that the value of 'description' cannot be null.

I don't have enough knowledge of triggers but there is an INSERT trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `charges_insert_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `charges`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DECLARE change_flag,header_id,sgl_trigger_flag int;
        DECLARE description, var_name varchar(500);
        SET description = "";
        SET change_flag = 0;
        SET var_name = "";
        SET sgl_trigger_flag = (SELECT count(*) FROM system_prefs WHERE prefname='sgl_trigger_flag' AND prefvalue = '1');
        IF sgl_trigger_flag <> 0
        THEN
        IF (SELECT @sgl_user_id IS NULL)
        THEN
            SET @sgl_user_id = 0;
            SET @sgl_user_name = "System User";
        END IF;        SET var_name = (SELECT name FROM products where sgl_id = NEW.product_id);
        SET description = CONCAT("Charge (ID: ",NEW.sgl_id,") for ", var_name," is added");
        IF NEW.opportunity_id > 0
        THEN

          INSERT INTO changes_log_headers(`user_id`, `user_name`, `changelog_table_name`, `type`, `created_on`, `record_id`, `description`,`account_id`) VALUES (@sgl_user_id,@sgl_user_name,'opportunities','update', NOW(), NEW.opportunity_id, description, NEW.account_id);  
        ELSE
          INSERT INTO changes_log_headers(`user_id`, `user_name`, `changelog_table_name`, `type`, `created_on`, `record_id`, `description`, `account_id`, `show_in_accounts`) VALUES (@sgl_user_id,@sgl_user_name,'accounts','update', NOW(), NEW.account_id, description, NEW.account_id, 1);  
        END IF;        END IF;
        END
```

Comment: Are there any triggers exists your structure ?

Comment: Post your table schema - `Describe table_name;`

Comment: I tried this and I have different output: "opportunity_id" doesn't have a default value". What version of MySQL do you have?

Comment: Sure u miss  a column in the table that cannot take on a NULL value.

Comment: Your error is caused by another linked table. `constraint violation` means that this table is linked with another one containing the `description` field that value is empty.

Comment: @Meloman yes u r correct I guess

Comment: Do you still have this error if you add values for fields opportunity_id, 
`invoice_id, 
status_comment,
mf_id,
payment_id,
auto_charge,
store_id,
booking_id,
reversal_charge_id,
revenue_reported`?

Comment: Now need to identify which table has this `description` field and why is it a constraint with it. Here I see only foreign keys containing ids (integers)... so description is not an integer normaly.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE changes_log_headers

If you have a test environment, drop the trigger and try your insert again.  From the code I see, changes_log_headers.description should be getting populated.

Comment: Thanks for your answers which pointed me in the right direction. There was an issue in the trigger, description field value was not being populated due to null result from products table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your tables linked with another table who have column name "`description`" which can not be NULL.

you should fill that field